# In Kotlin, what's the difference between the terms Coroutine and Continuation?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

It seems like these two terms are used interchangeably.  Yet, there also seems to be some difference that I'm struggling to put my finger on.  Is there a difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's true, these two are quite closely related. To resume a coroutine, you actually call `continuation.resume()`.

Each coroutine has its associated continuation object. Actually, you don't need anything else but that object, it contains the complete state of the coroutine.

To a certain degree, Kotlin uses "coroutine" to also include the coroutine dispatcher, which gives the coroutine the knowledge how exactly to suspend itself, where to keep the continuation while suspended, and how to resume (dispatch) it later. But you can also use the `Unconfined` dispatcher, which is almost as good as no dispatcher at all, and be in total control of resumption with nothing but the continuation object being preserved:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

var continuation: Continuation<Unit>? = null

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Unconfined) {
        println("Suspending")
        suspendCoroutine<Unit> { cont ->
            continuation = cont
        }
        println("Resumed!")
    }
    println("After launch")
    continuation!!.resume(Unit)
    println("After continuation.resume(Unit)")
}
```

Here you can see that we reproduced the whole suspend-resume scenario while keeping nothing but the `Continuation` object.

My conclusion is that, due to the features of Kotlin's coroutine design (especialy the fact that they are *stackless*), there's a blurry line between the concepts of "coroutine" and "continuation".

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Is there ever anything in memory that is a concrete instance of some `Coroutine` type, or is the concept of `Coroutine` always represented concretely only with an instance (can there be more than one?) of a `Continuation` type?

Comment: The `Coroutine` type doesn't even exist. The closest we have is `AbstractCoroutine` and its various subclasses. It mostly corresponds to a `Job`, so it's the object that manages coroutine execution.

Answer (score 3):

Coroutines are procedures that take turns doing their task and then suspend to give control to the other coroutines in the group, and resume task.

Continuation is the stack that controls the flow of the program, that allows it to skip into different parts of your program. You could use it to control the flow including coroutine like a global `switch`.

Comment: you should elaborate here.. seems like the explanation is following a correct path but is incomplete